# Debugging a copied web site in Visual Studio 2012 debugs the original

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a quick question about debugging in Visual studios 2012, 
I have copied an old website I had as I wanted to have one similar, I have changed its name, database connection and IIS app pool/site. 
I assumed that I had taken all references of the old websites name and have searched through the entire solution for references but when i press debug in VB2012 it loads the old website up.

Is there a path I need to change to fix this or is there something else I need to do.

Also, it would be nice to know where debug is actually working from to see how the process works.

Comment: Is this a web site (File->New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)? Also, how did you determine that it's debugging the original? Could it really be the new one? And what happens if you just run it without the debugger?

Comment: It is a web application, but I have already fixed it, the problem was in the project properties -- web--- I had to change where the project server URL pointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the project properties -- web--- I had to change where the project server URL pointed as it was pointing to the site I had cloned